# Twitter API detecting pinned tweets

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Is there a way of detecting a pinned tweet using the array returned from the twitter api? I have `print_r` the array returned and nothing indicates a tweet is pinned or not.

The method I currently use is

```
$statuses = $connection->get("statuses/home_timeline", array("count" => 25, "exclude_replies" => true));
```

The documentation does not mention pinned tweets https://twitteroauth.com/

Answer (score 3):

The user profile showed pinned tweets at some point in the past, but no longer.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?id=2705321

```
"has_extended_profile": true,
"default_profile": false,
"default_profile_image": false,
"pinned_tweet_ids": [
  451484520316153860
],
"has_custom_timelines": false,
```

Comment: Yep, looks like it was either removed or accidentally exposed to me at that time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's currently no way to either detect or set a pinned Tweet using the public Twitter APIs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get it through the API, but it's fairly easy to scrape the data from the website*.  The HTML has lots of useful semantic attributes which you can use.

Here's the HTML representation of my pinned Tweet.

```
<div 
    class="tweet original-tweet js-original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable cards-forward
    user-pinned" 
    data-tweet-id="554772317738659840"
    data-disclosure-type=""
    data-item-id="554772317738659840"
    data-permalink-path="/edent/status/554772317738659840"
    data-screen-name="edent"
    data-name="Terence Eden" 
    data-user-id="14054507"
    ...
```

Look for the `<div>` with the class `user-pinned` - then get the attribute `data-tweet-id`.  That will be the status ID which has been pinned.

*Check the T&Cs first!